# Macro not available under "run a script" selection list

Tags: vba, outlook

I have written a macro in Microsoft Outlook and it works.
I can go to developer tab > Macro and see my script in Project1.ThisOutlookSession.RunMyScript.

However, when I create a rule and select "Run a scipt", there's nothing for me to select.

When a specific email arrives, it should trigger my macro. My macro run a vbs file.

Comment: [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/).

Answer (score 0):

Run a script code cannot run as a standalone. It requires a specific format referencing an incoming item.

```vb
Sub myRuleCode(itm as Object)
    ' usually code that processes itm
End Sub
```